# Filter file names using glob?

Tags: php, database, file, web-applications, glob

I have list of files with file names with format as ttttyyyymmdd.txt i.e 4 digits before the timestamp. Here is an example 1322120120804.txt.The tttt are random integers generated for each file. I would like to use php glob to pick only files posted to day. So in my code currently I have

```
$dir="myfiles/";
glob($dir."1322".date('Ymd'));
```

This code picks only 1 file with kind of prefix 1322. How can I make it dynamic so that it reads all the files generate this date.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dir="myfiles/";
glob($dir."*".date('Ymd'));
```

Comment: I have tried but it is not working. It returns empty array.How can we modify it?

Comment: It worked. I had typo for directory. I have improvised it by checking if it exists if(is_dir($dir)){ //then action }

Answer (score 1):

The glob understands `[0-9]` like character groups so you can write:

```
 glob($dir."[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]".date('Ymd'));
```

On linux like systems php's glob is a wrapper around the similarly named posix function, so reading the [posix manual](http://linux.die.net/man/7/glob) could be useful in search of pattern capabilities.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your contribution. It is not working though. It returns an empty array yet the files are there and we are meeting this criteria. Any more suggestion.

Comment: Could it be that it's missing hte `.txt` from the end of the pattern? When i tried it it seemed to be working.

Comment: I had problems with my $dir first.Any way I didn't know how to do it and you guys gave me the idea. Thanks a bunch. It works perfect. I like it [0-9] than * because it act as a kind of validation. I fixed the .txt too